# Поставить блок <div> друг на против друга

Tags: html, css

Как сделать так, чтобы блок 3 встал напротив блока 1, а не напротив блока 2, как сейчас?

```css
.flex-container3 {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 215px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
}
.flex-item1 {
  order: 1;
  width: 80%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.comment1 {
  width: 45%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
}
.comment2 {
  width: 45%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 250px;
}
input {
  width: 250px;
}
.name {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-top: 35px;
}
.mail {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-top: 35px;
}
.commit {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-top: 35px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="flex-container3">
    <div class="flex-item1">
      <div class="comment1">
        <div class="name">1
          <input type="text" name="name" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="mail">2
          <input type="text" name="name" value="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="comment2">
        <div class="commit">3
          <input type="text" name="name" value="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.flex-item1 {
display: inline-flex;
}
```

```css
.flex-container3 {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 215px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.flex-item1 {
  order: 1;
  width: 80%;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.comment1 {
  width: 45%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
}

.comment2 {
  width: 45%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 250px;
}

input {
  width: 250px;
}

.name {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-top: 35px;
}

.mail {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-top: 35px;
}

.commit {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-top: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container3">
  <div class="flex-item1">
    <div class="comment1">
      <div class="name">1<input type="text" name="name" value=""></div>
      <div class="mail">2<input type="text" name="name" value=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="comment2">
      <div class="commit">3<input type="text" name="name" value=""></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло=)

Answer (score 1):

Еще можно было как вариант так сделать :)

```
.comment1 {
  width: 45%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: right;
}

.comment2 {
  width: 45%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 250px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.flex-item1 div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    float: left;
}
```

Или вот так. https://jsfiddle.net/92zha34t/

Answer (score 0):

[Вот здесь](http://frontender.info/a-guide-to-flexbox/) есть статья по Flexbox, которая более-менее суммирует необходимые для его использования знания.